# Postgresql split single row into multiple rows based on date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recursive-query

In my case, we have a table ABC with the supposed 1 row.

| id | name | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul | 01/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |

but while retrieving I would like to get multiple rows where the start date is incrementing by 1 like till it's less than or equal to the end date.

| id | name | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul | 01/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |
| 1 | Rahul | 02/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |
| 1 | Rahul | 03/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |
| 1 | Rahul | 04/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |
| 1 | Rahul | 05/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |
| 1 | Rahul | 06/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |

Please let me know how we can do that.

Comment: Join it with a generate series of dates https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series()`.  Assuming the data is by day:

```
select t.id, t.name, gs.date, t.end_date
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') gs(date);
```

If your data is actually by month, you would just change `'1 day'` to `'1 month'`.

Note:  Postgres allows set returning functions in the `select`, so you *could* write this as:

```
select t.id, t.name,
       generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') as date,
       t.end_date
from t;
```

However, I don't think that is a good practice.  I am uncomfortable with `select` expressions changing the number of rows being returned by a query.